# What is the best way to run background task in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am building an app where in user have to enter a time and a simple function will trigger on each day at that particular time. This can be handled when the app is in foreground. But when the app is in closed state. That is not using, I cannot find an efficient way to execute that function.

Added the minimal code snippet

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this.loadaccountDetail();
  this.interval = setInterval( () => this.setState(prevState => ({ timer: prevState.timer - 1 }) ),1000);
  SplashScreen.hide();
}


componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.timer === 1) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}


async loadaccountDetail() {
  let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem("id");
  const user = JSON.parse(userId);
  this.setState({ user: user });
  try {
    var that = this;
    var date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    var expirydate = this.props.matchapprovedate; //You can set your own date-time
    var diffr = moment.duration(moment(expirydate).diff(moment(date)));
    var hours = parseInt(diffr.asHours());
    var minutes = parseInt(diffr.minutes());
    var seconds = parseInt(diffr.seconds());
    var d = hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
    //converting in seconds
    that.setState({ totalDuration: d });
    if(d == 10){
      this.abortDate()
    }
    else{
      console.log('not now')
    }
    this.setState({ data: !this.state.data });
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log("catch:" + err);
  }
}

abortDate() {
  ApiService.abortDate({ userid: this.props.userid })
  .then(async response => {
    if (response.status == 1) {
      NavigationService.navigate("news");
      ToastService.showToast("You canceled the date sucessfully","error",3000);
    }
    else {
      ToastService.showToast("Not able to cancel date", "error", 3000);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
}

render() {
  const { matchapprovedate } = this.props;
  const { userid } = this.props;

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <CountDown
        digitStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
        digitTxtStyle={{ padding: 0, color: "#998299"}}
        timeLabelStyle={{ color: "#998299"}}
        until={this.state.totalDuration}
        //duration of countdown in seconds
        timeToShow={["H", "M", "S"]}
        timeLabels={{ h: "HH", m: "MM", s: "SS" }}
        onFinish={() => console.log('finished')}
        //on Finish call
        size={30}
      />

    </View>
  )
}
```

As mentioned when the var d becomes 10 i want a function to be called which cannot be called until this screen is mounted that is the app is opened once.

Comment: add your code !

Comment: Please check the new edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [React Native Background Task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task), though it cannot execute your task reliably at a specific time (ie: 14:30 might execute at 14:50), it is explained in the git hub page as

> The exact timings of task execution are unpredictable, as both Anrdoid and iOS use black-box algorithms, which depend on factors like device sleep state. This library should only be used for tasks that are an incremental feature, and can have inexact timing, such as the periodic background syncing of data. You should be prepared for the case that background task doesn't fires at all.

Comment: Yes, i went through the readme file and also many other links and found that. Handling process in background is very buggy in react native. However i will have to handle it in backend